# Some services are not able to be constructed - Error while validating the service descriptor In Worker Service .Net Core 3.1(Dependency Injection)

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, service, worker

Creating Worker service in .Net Core 3.1. Referred Business Logic in Worker service.

In Business logic i am using Db Context.

```
      public class CountryService : ICountryService {
            private readonly projectDbContext _dbContext;
            public CountryService (projectDbContext  dbContext) {
                _dbContext = dbContext;
            }
            // public CountryService(){

            // }
            public IEnumerable<object> GetCountrys () {
                try {
                            //Code
                     }
               Catch(System.Exception){
                   throw ex;
                    }
}
```

Worker Service Program.cs

```
         public static void Main (string[] args) {
            try {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder ()
                    .SetBasePath (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory ()) //location of the exe file
                    .AddJsonFile ("appsettings.json", optional : true, reloadOnChange : true);

                IConfiguration Configuration = builder.Build ();

                CreateHostBuilder (args).ConfigureServices ((hostContext, services) => {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker> ()
                        .Configure<EventLogSettings> (c => {
                            c.LogName = "Sample Service";
                            c.SourceName = "Sample Service Source";
                        });
                    services.AddScoped<ICountryService, CountryService> ();
                    //services.AddTransient<ICountryService> (_ => _.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ICountryService>> ().Value);
                    services.AddDbContext<iDepoDbContext> (options =>
                        options.UseNpgsql (Configuration.GetConnectionString ("PostGresqlDevConnection")));
                }).Build ().Run ();
            } catch (System.Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            } 

        }
```

Worker.cs

```
 public class Worker : BackgroundService {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly ICountryService _countryService;

        public Worker (ICountryService countryService) {
            _countryService = countryService;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync (CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
            try {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                    // _logger.LogInformation ("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                    var countries = _countryService.GetCountrys ();
                    await Task.Delay (1000, stoppingToken);
                }
       } catch (System.Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
       }

        }
    }
```

Error Message

> "Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: ExcelUploadService.Worker': Cannot consume scoped service 'iProjectWeb.Application.Interface.Master.Geography.ICountryService' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)"

Comment: Could you provide a full example to troubleshoot? I am unable to debug your code partly because you have not defined ie. "projectDbContext". Your error was the same as mine (for a .net core 3.1 API program), and I fixed them by ensuring that all required services was actually being hosted on program startup. Perhaps this link could be helpful in that regard: https://andrewlock.net/new-in-asp-net-core-3-service-provider-validation/

Comment: Have the same problem - Get the error when the scoped class requires an injected dbContext. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
    private IServiceScopeFactory Services { get; }
    
    public Worker(IServiceScopeFactory services)
    {
        Services = services;
    }
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync (CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var myScopedService = scope.GetRequiredService<ICountryService>();
            // ... Use the service here ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 complete example with Background Service

```
using HR.Data.Interface.UOW;

namespace HR.API.Backgrounds
{
    public sealed class OutgoingEmailService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<OutgoingEmailService> _logger;
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

        public OutgoingEmailService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, ILogger<OutgoingEmailService> logger) => (_serviceScopeFactory, _logger) = (serviceScopeFactory, logger);

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("OutgoingEmailService.ExecuteAsync - Loop");

                using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    using (var unitOfWork = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>())
                    {
                        var test = unitOfWork.AuditLogService.Get(1);
                    }
                }

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't show an example of the scoped class  requires injection - "CountryService (projectDbContext  dbContext)".